# I have a counter based if/else statement but for some reason the else won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, counter

The if segment works but not the else which can be seen when you try to click the minimize button as it will expand but will not contract unfortunately.

```
$("#scfullscreen").click(function() {
sccount+=1;
if (sccount % 2 !== 0) {
    animateFn('20%','80%');

} else {
    animateFN('0','20%');
    }
});
```

The problem is i dont know what is causing it not to work here is the rest of the javascript

```
    var sccount = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#scfullscreen").click(function() {
    sccount+=1;
    if (sccount % 2 !== 0) {
        animateFn('20%','80%');

    } else {
        animateFN('0','20%');
        }
    });
    });

    function animateFn(l, w){
        $('#soundcloud').animate({
                left: l,
                width: w,
            }, 1000);
        $('#scfullscreen').animate({
                left: l,
                width: w,
            }, 1000);
        $('#scexpand').addClass('rotated');
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>L3mmy Dubz</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <a href="index.html">
            <div id="homebtn" class="btn">Home</div>
        </a>
        <div id="musicbtn" class="btn">Music</div>
        <iframe id="soundcloud" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/19690125&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
        <div class="btn" id="scfullscreen" class="scfullscreenclick">
            <img id="scexpand" height="100%" alt="fullscreen" src="images\plus.png" />
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

And here is my CSS

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    background-color:#B22800;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #7C1C00;
    opacity:0.9;

}
.btn {
    position:fixed;
    line-height:200%;
    text-overflow:clip;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:7.5%;
    width:20%;
    color:white;
    Font-size:2em;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color:#ff3a00;
}
#homebtn{
    top:0%;
}
#musicbtn{
    top:7.5%;
}
#header a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}

#soundcloud {
    width:20%;
    height:77.5%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:15%;
}
#scfullscreen {
    bottom:0px;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:7.5%;
    left:0px;
    width:20%;
}
#scfullscreen:hover {
    background-color:#ff3a00;
}
.rotated {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Opera */
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #header {
        width:30%;
    }
    #soundcloud {
        width:30%;
    }
    #scfullscreen {
        width:30%;
        left:0px;
    }
}
```

Any help that can be given is greatly appreciated as i am new to javascript but i am yet to find a problem with it online.

p.s. my site can be found here if it is easier to check through that http://l3mmydubz.onhub.online
Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: You should debug your program. Walk through it, step by step, with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Typo wrote animateFN instead of animateFn 'facepalm' thank you for the help though it is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your `if` statement test expression:

```
if (!sccount%2 === 0) {
```

The expression `!sccount%2` is interpreted as if it were parenthesized like this:

```
if ( (!sccount) % 2 === 0)
```

When `sccount` is non-zero, `!sccount` will be `false`. In turn, `false` will be converted to `0` in the `%` expression, so the answer is *always* zero unless `sccount` is `0`.

If you just want to toggle between two actions based on whether `sccount` is even or odd, you can use `!==` to compare the result:

```
if ( sccount % 2 !== 0 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i have implemented this. However for some reason it is still not working for me.

Comment: @JamesAnderson if you don't post another question or extend this one, nobody will be able to help, I'm afraid. You'll also need to explain exactly what you mean when you say it's not working: does *anything* happen? Do you get errors in the browser console?